# IE jQuery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

HTML:

```
<div id="media-photo">
    <img src="/uploads/photos/16.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<a href="/uploads/photos/5.jpg" class="img">
    <img src="/uploads/photos-thumbs/5.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="/uploads/photos/6.jpg" class="img">
    <img src="/uploads/photos-thumbs/6.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.img').click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#media-photo img').attr('src', path);

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**

What the above code is supposed to do is when you click on an anchor (with class img), the image in the #media-photo div get changed to a new one based on the anchor's href attribute (the href is a relative path to an image, it replaces the current img's src attribute).

It works great in Firefox.

In IE (version 8 specifically, I haven't tested older versions yet), what happens that when you click on the anchor the image opens in the browser instead.

How to make this work in IE, too?

EDIT:

I have solved the problem by using try {} finally {} to make sure the function returns false (to prevent the default behavior). Here is the entire jQuery code (I have simplified it greatly above not to confuse people with irrelevant stuff):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box-content2 a.img').click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $('img', this).attr('alt');
        var description = jQuery.trim($(this).attr('title'));
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (id != $('#media-photo img').attr('id')) {

            try {

                $('#media-photo img').attr('src', path);
                $('#media-photo img').attr('alt', title);
                $('#media-photo img').attr('id', id);

                $('#content h2:first').text('You Are Viewing "' + title + '"');
                $('title').text('You Are Viewing "' + title + '"');

                if (description.length > 0) {
                    $('#content .box-container:first').removeClass('invisible');
                    $('#content .box-container:first p').text(description);
                } else {
                    $('#content .box-container:first').addClass('invisible');
                }

                var action = '/view/favoriting-form/id/' + id;

                $.get(action, function(data) {
                    if ($('.favoriting').length > 0) {
                    $('.favoriting').replaceWith(data);
                    } else {
                        $('#actions h3').after(data);
                    }
                });

                action = '/view/rating-form/id/' + id;

                $.get(action, function(data) {
                    if ($('.rating').length > 0) {
                        $('.rating').replaceWith(data);
                    } else {
                        if ($('.favoriting').length > 0) {
                            $('.favoriting').after(data);
                        } else {
                            $('#actions h3').after(data);
                        }
                    }
                    $('.star').rating();
                });

                action = '/view/add-media-comment/id/' + id;

                $.get(action, function(data) {
                    $.getScript('/js/photo.js');
                    $('#media-comments').html(data);
                });

            } finally {

                return false;
            }

        }

        return false;
    });
    $('#add_to_favorites').hover(function() {
        var id = $('#media-photo img').attr('id');
        var action = '/view/photo/id/' + id;
        $('.favoriting').attr('action', action);
    });
    $('#rate-button').hover(function() {
        var id = $('#media-photo img').attr('id');
        var action = '/view/photo/id/' + id;
        $('.rating').attr('action', action);
    });
    $('a.previous-media, a.next-media').click(function() {
        var id = $('#media-photo img').attr('id');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href.split('/');
        var p = href[href.length - 1];
        var url = '/view/album-photos/id/' + id + '/p/' + p;

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $.getScript('/js/photo.js');
            $('.box-content2').html(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
    $('#media-comments form').submit(function() {
        var id = $('#media-photo img').attr('id');
        var url = '/view/add-media-comment/id/' + id;

        var postData = $(this).serialize() + '&add_comment=Submit';
        $.post(url, postData, function(data) {
            $.getScript('/js/photo.js');
            $('#media-comments').html(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your simplified example works for me in IE7. Have you tried running this actual code above in IE8, or just your more complicated version?

Comment: Your code works for me in both IE8 with and without compatibility mode.  However, it does NOT work for me in Firefox, which navigates to the image rather than loading it into the img tag.

Comment: I have solved the problem already guys (by using try {} finally {} block so even in case something goes wrong in the js it still returns false).

Comment: @Michael: What version of Firefox. It works great here in 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
if (id != $('#media-photo img').attr('id')) {
```

Where does `id` come from?

Comment: I have removed that line. It actually comes from the anchor (each anchor has id attribute, the markup is more complicated so I have simplified it as much as possible) like this var id = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: Just to clarify that is not the problem certainly, I have checked the id with alert and it has correct value, I have also tried removing the if condition and the problem persists.

Comment: I have solved the problem by using try {} finally {}, check the original post, I have updated it.

Comment: OKkkkkk but wouldn't it be better to fix the exception? :)

Comment: It would be but I'm not sure where the exception occurs. I have tested the page in both Firefox and IE8 now and all seems to work, all ajax requests and all other stuff that's happening in the click event() seems to execute properly.

Comment: Is it really correct to choose this as the "answer" when it doesn't really provide one?

Comment: Well I don't like to leave posts without answer so I choose something even when my question doesn't get answered.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, try this quickly and tell me if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.img').click(function(ev) {
        var path = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#media-photo img').attr('src', path);
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: There's something else going on, I just dropped your code into a test page and it works fine in IE8. Can you give us any more information?

Comment: I have solved the problem by using try {} finally {}, check the original post, I have updated it.